# Cannot find Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Programmatically C#

Tags: c#, windows, package

Hi I was running the following code on my pc:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sbProductCode = new StringBuilder(39);
        int iIdx = 0;
        while (
            0 == MsiEnumProducts(iIdx++, sbProductCode))
        {
            Int32 productNameLen = 512;
            StringBuilder sbProductName = new StringBuilder(productNameLen);

            MsiGetProductInfo(sbProductCode.ToString(),
                "ProductName", sbProductName, ref productNameLen);

            if (sbProductName.ToString().Contains("Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable"))
            {
                Int32 installDirLen = 1024;
                StringBuilder sbInstallDir = new StringBuilder(installDirLen);

                MsiGetProductInfo(sbProductCode.ToString(),
                    "InstallLocation", sbInstallDir, ref installDirLen);

                Console.WriteLine("ProductName {0}: {1}",
                    sbProductName, sbInstallDir);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

The loop ends and nothing is found. 
However looking at Programs and Features in Control Panel I can clearly see that it is installed, and the name matches exactly in the string.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because MSI "products" do not correspond 1:1 to the entries shown in the user-facing Programs and Features list. For the VC 2015 x64 runtime installed on Windows 7, you need to look for two products: `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Minimum Runtime` and `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 x64 Additional Runtime`.

Comment: Thank you, how do I find out which Redistributables correspond to which products? I have tried searching everywhere.

Comment: You can either determine them by trial and error (install a redistributable package on a clean system, run the tool, see what products appear), or inspect the unpacked redistributable MSI/MSM file contents (downloaded, or found in Visual Studio installation directory) with the Windows Installer tools from Windows SDK and get the product names from there.